# C# application runs but doesn't compile changes?

Tags: c#, .net

My .NET framework 4.6.1 console application works fine on my friends computer but after cloning the repository and running it on mine it seems to not want to compile. Everything still works the same as it did when I tried debugging and noticed it wasn't working.

Any other application I try compiles fine, this is a bug with this project only.

**Extra details, as I was told I didn't example enough?**
I've tried compiling it pretty much every way, clicking the Start button with the green triangle, F5, CTRL+F5 and none compile the code. It runs just as it would if it worked, it just doesn't apply changes I've made in the source code when debugging. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Hi Dev. I understand your frustration and want to help. But you need to describe the technical problem itself in more detail. How do you try to compile it? Edit the question and describe what you do and what happens.

Comment: You could get hundreds of possible solutions to your question. It’s not specific enough, this isn’t the right place for your question as it’s too broad.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when trying to compile? If so, post them.

Comment: No, as I said in my question it runs perfectly fine when I start it. I've updated my question with more information @LeonBambrick

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio, deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders in your project, then re-open Visual Studio and try compile. The `obj` and `bin` folders are automatically generated during compilation so you should be safe to delete them.

Comment: @rshepp I appreciate your response, but I've seen that in around 4 other questions and I stated I already tried most, although thankyou.

Comment: We can't read your mind. If you don't post exactly what you tried in your question, then we don't know exactly what you tried.

Comment: I can't remember what I tried, but when you mention things they come back to you, just like they would with anyone else. If I listed everything I had tried I would be here for a long time, and I don't think SO would even allow a question that long :)

Comment: @rshepp When trying your comment I receive an error when compiling. `Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\application\bin\Debug\application.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to the point at the correct location for the target assembly.`

Comment: I can see why your reputation dropped from your current to the preview in your BIO now, lol. If you read the rest of the question you'll see I've implemented a fair amount of information on the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to **Build > Configuration Manager**

With `Active solution configuration` set to `Debug`, make sure that your console application project has the `Build` checkbox ticked. This is usually ticked by default.

Otherwise you can explicitly build your project by selecting **Build > Build ProjectName** (Shift+F6) or right-clicking your project in the solution explorer and selecting Build from the context menu.

Comment: If the application runs fine, as he says, but doesn't debug, this seems likely.